# How to move picture to another div in tririum

Tags: moovweb, tritium

If I have something like this:

```
<div class="class1">
    <img src="image.jpg" id="image1">
</div>
```

How do I move this image to another div in tritium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work, try it out (`class2` is the id of the class to what you want to move the image):

```
$("//div[contains(@class,'class2')]") {
  move_here("//img[@id='image1']")
}
```

There might be other ways but this is quite simple and working.

Comment: I've made a play.tritium.io example given your solution here:  http://play.tritium.io/6526e5d20c148c1634bb8094fffb8c55a13c3d76

Comment: Using move_to is the same, except the xpath's are reversed: http://play.tritium.io/b55fd00f69ce0dc497198806d5ed0b816c04abf0

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I need to use `move_to()` but I don't know how exactly. If someone explain I'd be glad.

Answer (score 0):

```
html() {
 $("//img[@id='image1']") {
  move_to("//div[contains(@class,'class2')]")
  }
 }
```

Can also be done using move_to function.
http://tester.tritium.io/6526e5d20c148c1634bb8094fffb8c55a13c3d76